# How to make css dropdown from href divs

Tags: html, css

I have some divs with images in my script with href function to click on.

```
<div class="home"><a href="index.php?pagina=home"></a></div>
<div class="events"><a href="index.php?pagina=events"></a></div>
<div class="contact"><a href="index.php?pagina=contact"></a></div>
```

To make the site responsive I need to change this to a **css** dropdown menu.
Is this possible without changing the script?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "not changing the script". You will have to change your code to make this into a CSS drop-down.

Comment: "not changing te script" means not possible to change code snippet above because it is used on many pages. (Yes I know, not the best way but it's an old one) So that's why I like to to something in CSS to transfer it to a dropdown menu. Why the 1 downvote? It's a clear question!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jQuery plug-in [SlickNav](http://slicknav.com/) which can alter your desktop menu to mobile menu automatically. You might need to adjust your markup (do not call it "script", it's not) to work with the plug-in, but you won't need to write code for both mobile and desktop, one will suffice for both with some tweaking.